# Is it possible to detect whether jdb has set a valid breakpoint?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jdb

When debugging using intellij idea, if I'm connected to a remote jvm, valid breakpoints will turned to a red check mark, and invalid checkpoints will turn into a grey icon.
But when I use gbd to `stop at noWhere.noClass:noLine`, it will not tell me that this is a invalid break point. Is there any way to do so? Or maybe anyidea how idea did this?
Tks in advance.